# Changing background color in graph-tool

Tags: python, cairo, graph-visualization, graph-drawing, graph-tool

I'm setting about to use a python package named [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html) to visualize graphs. For some reason it sets grey background color each time saving a graph, which looks far from pleasant. Anyone knows how to change it to white?

For example, this sample code:

```
from graph_tool.all import *
g = price_network(5000)
p = sfdp_layout(g)
graph_draw(g, pos=p, output="example.png")
```

being run on iPython notebook, displays graph with white background on the screen, but saved picture has grey background.

The outcome is the same whatever format is used for output (at least with .png, .pdf and .svg). With networkX there was no such a problem, but graph drawing there is slower and much less flexible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just pass the `bg_color` option to graph_draw(). For example:

```
graph_draw(g, pos=p, bg_color=[1,1,1,1], output="example.png")
```

will produce a white background, instead of transparent.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, with a single argument! Thank you. I think this should be documented at http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html

Comment: Hope more questions on StackOverflow will make graph-tool more popular tool for graph processing. As yet, I think, it is the lack of questions on web that hinders graph-tool from being more competitive than networkX, for example.

Comment: Yes, this is an omission. I'll add it to the documentation.

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto How come `gprops={"bgcolor":"white"}` does not work as intended, does it not get sent to graphviz or are the graphviz arguments incorrect?

Comment: @Hooked You are confusing two different functions, ``graph_draw()``, and ``graphviz_draw()``. The second uses graphviz, the first does not. The ``gprops`` parameter should only be passed to the second function. (Note that graphviz_draw() is deprecated)

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto: the documentation says that you bg_color can be a string, but this is not true, I think. https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html?highlight=bg_color

Answer (score 2):

The "grey background color" that you see is your PNG viewers way of rendering the transparent background. For example, I see a checkerboard pattern on my screen:

[image]

but when I upload the image or print it out anywhere it has a (default) white background:

[image]

Flatten the image in an editor to remove the alpha channel if it bothers you.

**In theory** you should be able to pass `gprops={"bgcolor":"white"}` to [graph_draw](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw) but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you if you would recommend some freeware for flatting png's on Mac OSX?

Comment: @kurtosis Happy to help! If this answers your question please accept the answer so we know this is what you are looking for. An awesome freeware alternative to photoshop is GIMP - it's quite simple to remove an alpha channel using it!

Comment: Finally I accepted another answer providing solution with the single argument to graph_draw. You were almost right about bicolor!